# Affect of network interruption on Paypal payment gateway

Tags: android, android-studio

I am new in Android development and want to ask, If I am using webview for the Payment in my Mobile App. And I successfully load the page of payment and filled up all the necessary information then if my transaction is in process and the network interrupts and I have done the payment from my side and the transaction failed. My balance was deducted from my account due to interruption. So, Is there any way to check in Android that I have already done the payment and get the history of that?

Answer (score 0):

So you can do one thing then when he started payment gateway send that details to backend and if you don't get transaction details make it transaction failed and show it in myorders page .If you got transaction id then you can make it order placed and show success message in myorders page through get url .If network fails and the order is not placed but amount debited from the acount give a chance to customer send email to you so you can revert it from business paypal.

Comment: Thanks for answering me  I got your solution but my question is little bit different. If during transaction amount was debited from the account and network interrupts and I didn't receive the payment so how can I send the success url to the user. In that case what should i do?

Comment: Can you tell me how you receiving the transaction id data?